# Notation shorthand for two notes going in quick succession

Tags: notation

Ex.
[image: example picture]
Could these 32-notes be notated as one note with some ornamentation/articulation? Is there a standard shorthand notation for that?

Comment: What's the music?

Comment: It's from Fortress theme by Paul Romero from Heroes of Might and Magic III (excellent video game with excellent music :-)) I got it specifically from this cover https://youtu.be/LMzOHfOSRl0 around 0:51, left hand. To download the sheets you'd need to become Patron on the pianist's Patreon page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: there's no ornament or articulation that does what you want.

The only possible shorthand would be to write the first demisemiquaver (thirty-second note) as a  single semiquaver (sixteenth note) with a short oblique line through its stem. But it looks fine as it is. Why do you want to change it? Does it go on for bar after bar?

Comment: There are 7 consecutive bars going similarly like this (just in different chords).

Comment: I'm interested in this because I often try to make notation as short as possible - to save space, reduce page turns. I've converted i.e. lots of songs to be played from a tablet screen (using Transcribe!, Photoscore and Dorico) I guess my use case is playing from an electronic device, because I don't like messing around with lot's of paper sheets and I have usually a tablet by hand.

Comment: If there are 7 bars of it, what I might do is write the first occurrence 'correctly' and each subsequent one as I described: with the line through its stem. It's fairly standard practice to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're thinking of something like this?   I suppose it saves just a little ink! (Whoops! My ties have got a bit messed up.)

Better to just notate it properly.

[image]

Comment: Yes - that'd work. I don't recognise the piece though, and if the tempo's really slow your little notes could end up sounding a bit late and rushed.